# How to skip music tracks with screen off?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, music-player, volume-control

Is there a way to skip songs/music with hardware buttons and without having to turn on the phones screen?

A while ago, I had a phone with a custom ROM that allowed me to skip between songs by long pressing the volume buttons. Long press in VOL+ changed to the next track, and in VOL - to previous track. It was very useful, specially when I was driving, having my phone connected via a simple 3.5 plug to plug cable (to the aux. port), so i could just grab the phone, and press the keys without having to even look at it.

Now, with my new phone, and stock ROM (4.1.2) , I don't have that option, so are there some apps or hacks that i could use to allow such functionality?

I am already rooted, but there are (currently) no custom roms for my device (a motorola RAZR D3 XT919),

so what is my best option?

Comment: Did you try double tapping and triple tapping volume buttons?

Comment: Are you using a headset that comes with a button (normally used to accept incomning calls)? If so, search the playstore for "headset button" or "headset control" gives you a bunch of apps that let you use that button to skip, fast-forward, rev, adjust volume, and more using a kind of "morse code" with the single button (e.g. long tap = louder, short tap = play/stop, two short taps = next, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Smart Pocket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartvibration) app, you can skip tracks with single or double volume clicks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you cant.but you can shake your phone to change tracks. try [fusion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lava.music&hl=en).it has wave control too.